# Finding data patterns in sequential Postgresql rows

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, data-mining

I'd like to ask Postgres how often two occurrences of an event, one occurrence per row, are seen. For example, if I have user events like:

- User 1: Clicked button 1, redirected to page 2
- User 1: Clicked button 2, redirected to page 3
- User 1: Clicked button 18, redirected to page 100
- User 1: Clicked button 1, redirected to page 2
- User 1: Clicked button 2, redirected to page 3

then I would see the pattern ((button 1, page 2) => (button 2, page 3)) counted as two occurances.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

It's a very good question and has a fairly simple solution. Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to find out which user shows what sort of repeated behavior.

Please see the fiddle example **[here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/12aa6/2)** which discusses the DDL and the query I have used to get the desired result.

From your description I recommend you create a table for storing user events as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE t_clickevent (
   clickevent_id        INTEGER,
   user_id              INTEGER,
   clicked_button_id   INTEGER,
   redirected_url_id   INTEGER);
```

Add any more columns as and when you require. This is just a minimal structure.

Use the query as follows:

```
SELECT user_id, clicked_button_id,
       redirected_url_id
  FROM t_clickevent
GROUP BY user_id, clicked_button_id,
       redirected_url_id
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

**Output:**

```
USER_ID     CLICKED_BUTTON_ID     REDIRECTED_URL_ID
----------- --------------------- -----------------
1           1                     2
1           2                     3
```

Cheers!